# Can't store inputs from JTextField to filewriter

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, jtextfield, joptionpane

I'm trying to make a phone directory where the user has to enter multiple inputs using JTextField. I also have a search option that will search the inputted name from the directory in filewriter and I just can't seem to store my inputs in the filewriter. This is my initial code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menu = 0;
    
    boolean quit = false;
    do{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Telephone Directory Management System"
            + "\n1. Add a Student"
            + "\n2. Search"
            + "\n3. Sort Data"
            + "\n4. List of all data"
            + "\n5. Exit"
            + "\n\nPlease enter your choice:","Main Menu",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    menu = Integer.parseInt(input);
        
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                JTextField student = new JTextField();
                JTextField name = new JTextField();
                JTextField address = new JTextField();
                JTextField phone = new JTextField();
                
                Object[] fields = {
                    "Enter Student ID:",student,
                    "Enter Name:",name,
                    "Enter Address:",address,
                    "Enter Phone No.:",phone};
                int add = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,fields,"Add a Student",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                if (add == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                {

                    String student1 = student.getText();
                    String name1 = name.getText();
                    String address1 = address.getText();
                    String phone1 = phone.getText();
                    
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("directory.txt"), true);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    out.write(student1 + " " + name1 + " " + address1 + " " + phone1);
                    out.newLine();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter name to search information:","Search",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                File f = new File("directory.txt");
                try {
                    BufferedReader freader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                    String s;
                    while ((s = freader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] st = s.split(" ");
                        String id = st[0];
                        String nm = st[1];
                        String add1 = st[2];
                        String phoneNo = st[3];
                        if (input.equals(nm)) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Student ID: "+id+"\nName: "+nm+"\nAddress: "+add1+"\nPhone No.: "+phoneNo+"","Information",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    freader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                break;
```

I tried using scanner before and it does store my inputs but I need to use JOptionPane in this one. Thank you so much to anyone that can help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close the BufferedWriter after writing into it, like this

```
out.close()
```

If you don't do this the BufferedWriter won't flush what you've written into it to the underlying stream.

Comment: Hi!. I clearly forgot this one and after having it, it still won't store in the directory. I also tried using scanner along the JTextfield but it just keeps on running while the JOption window is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Are you sure you added out.close() after out.newLine() in the case 1 and recompiled? I tried the program on my computer and I see the line in the directory.txt file after adding a Student.

Comment: I tried coding it again and also deleting the directory to make sure and it now works!! Thank you so much bro. This really means a lot to me

Comment: No problem! If possible, can you mark the answer as useful with the upward arrow? I'm not sure what you see as the owner of the Question. Thank you and have a nice day.